# How to join with table after?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the foloowing model request:

```
$order = Order::findOrFail($request->order_id);
```

How to call `with("user")` after like:

```
$user = $order->with("user");

if($user->user()->count()){
    echo "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy eager load the data by using the [`load()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) method instead of `with()`:

```
$user = $order->load('user');
```

Comment: May be at once to load like: `Order::with("user")->findOrFail($request->order_id);` ?

Comment: Of course, you can do that, but the question was how to load the data after. If you don't need to load it after, use `with()`

Comment: @Daniel I didn't test it, but I don't think there is any difference. Use `with()` where you can.